# mySQL : fetch multidimensional arrays separated and sorted by date column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

In a mySQL `invoice` table there is also a `date` column like this `02.08.2016` (dd.mm.yy). Now when I query the table and fetch rows sorted by the date column I need finally a result with multidimensional arrays separated by months. The `SELECT` statement is simply this ;

```
SELECT * FROM inv ORDER BY date ASC
```

The fetched result should look like this:

```
  array [0] { 

           array [0] {
             [num]  => [230]
             [date] => [02.08.2016] // august
             [...]
           }

           array [1] {
             [num]  => [231]
             [date] => [02.08.2016] // august
             [...]
           }
           ...
   }

    array [1] { 

           array [0] {
             [num]  => [350]
             [date] => [10.09.2016] // september
             [...]
           }

           array [1] {
             [num]  => [351]
             [date] => [02.09.2016] // september
             [...]
           }
           ...
    }

    ...
```

I need this to create at the end for each month a separate CSV export file. Can I achieve this with a clever mySQL statement or do I need to process the result array afterwards with PHP tools? If so, what would be the most efficient way to do that?

Any help and suggestions are welcome

EDIT :

There seems to be a missunderstanding. To make it more clear, I need  arrays which lists all available invoices per month. Lets say there are 10 month in the table then there should be 10 arrays from 0..9. Each of these arrays then lists all available invoices per month as arrays (as I figured out below). Lets say array 0 (first month) contains 100 arrays of invoices. Then each invoice array has a set of cells (col) corresponding 1:1 to columns of the table (not summing something). So the answer of this.lau_ must have a different approach. It does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by year/month and then apply an aggregate function on your `num` (for example `AVG`, `SUM`, etc.). That should work:

```
SELECT
    extract(year_month FROM date) as month,
    SUM(num) as sum_num
FROM inv
GROUP BY month ORDER BY month ASC;
```

Comment: see my EDIT above